# inputting a one liner "foreach ..." in beamer (works fine in article)

Tags: beamer, input, foreach

I have a problem which could be minimally reduced to the following.

To begin with, the following code works just fine:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \p in {first,second}
{
    \begin{frame}

        \p

    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Though, if I change this line

```
\foreach \p in {first,second}
```

with

```
\input{forEachToBeInput.tex}
```

where `forEachToBeInput.tex` is a file containing a single line
(ie, "`\foreach \p in {first,second}`", obviously) and remove the `frame` environment, then I start to get a bunch of errors, like "`Paragraph ended before pgffor@next was complete`"..

Note that, interestingly, if I use document class Article, then all is fine!

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: what do you mean by "and remove the `frame` environment"? edit: I guess you mean "if I use `article` class, naturally removing the `frame` environment, all is fine".

Comment: @jfbu: indeed!!

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain the difference between the `beamer` and the `article`  context,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that the `\input` tokens are followed by something else and not directly by the `{\begin{frame}...\end{frame}}` part.

You can solve the problem by using the expandable version of `\input` as suggested in the other answer, but there's a less complex way:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{forEachToBeInput.tex}
\foreach \p in {first,second}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\foreachfromfile}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  % load the file contents in \temp
  \CatchFileDef\temp{#1}{}
  \expandafter\endgroup\temp
}

\begin{document}

\foreachfromfile{forEachToBeInput}
  {
    \begin{frame}

        \p

    \end{frame}
  }

\end{document}
```

The grouping is made so no definition of `\temp` is left behind.

A similar approach that requires to save in the file only the list and not the `\foreach` part.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{forEach.tex}
first,second
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand\foreachfromfile[2]{
  \CatchFileDef\foreachfromfilevariable{#2}{}%
  \foreach #1 in \foreachfromfilevariable
}

\begin{document}

\foreachfromfile\p{forEach}
  {
    \begin{frame}

        \p

    \end{frame}
  }

\end{document}
```

The mandatory `expl3` version:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{forEach.tex}
first,second
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__giulio_foreach_tl
\clist_new:N \l__giulio_foreach_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\foreachfromfile}{m +m}
 {% #1 is the file name, #2 the actions to perform
  \tl_set_from_file:Nnn \l__giulio_foreach_tl { } { #1 }
  % normalize to a clist
  \clist_set:NV \l__giulio_foreach_clist \l__giulio_foreach_tl
  % map the clist
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__giulio_foreach_tl { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foreachfromfile{forEach}
  {
    \begin{frame}

        #1

    \end{frame}
  }

\end{document}
```

As you see, no pseudovariable is needed. The current item in the list is denoted simply by `#1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The third block I did not understand tbh, but that fine. What I particularly like is the second, where forEach.tex needs to contain only the list: actually that was my first attempt, but did not work properly. May I ask you if (still in the second example) I can do \foreachfromfile \p {forEach} (with spaces)? I tried it and it looks fine, but want to be sure it s safe and robust (actually I would have naively expected \foreachfromfile{\p}{forEach}..

Comment: Sorry one more thing: How would you compare your solution (say part 1, so we compare like for like) with jfbu's?

Comment: @Giulio They are essentially the same, but using `\@@input` can be tricky in some circumstances.

Comment: I see thanks. How about using catchfile? Any risk that it interferes with other pacakges?

Comment: @Giulio I'd say it's well written and has no known incompatibilities, at least to me.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{forEachToBeInput.tex}
\foreach \p in {first,second}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\csname @@input\endcsname forEachToBeInput.tex
{
    \begin{frame}

        \p

    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

(the `filecontents` packages is used only to make this answer self-contained)

---

(moved from comment)

You can simplify the above by adding

```
\makeatletter\let\xxinput\@@input\makeatother
```

to the preamble and then use

```
\xxinput forEachToBeInput.tex
{
  <etc>
```

---

As per the explanation, a trace of the macro expansion reveals that at some
stage TeX will have to expand this

```
\@addtofilelist {forEachToBeInput.tex}\filehook@atbegin {forEachToBeInput.tex}\@@input forEachToBeInput.tex<space token here>\filehook@atend {forEachToBeInput.tex}
```

which means that at some point there will be

```
\foreach \p in {first,second}\filehook@atend {forEachToBeInput.tex}
```

and `\foreach` doesn't like that.

This `\filehook@atend` is not part of LaTeX kernel, nor is it provided by the standard classes.

I recruited Sherlock Holmes and he found this macro was provided by package `filehook` which is loaded by package `sansmathaccent` which is loaded by package `beamerbasefont`.

```
\ifbeamer@sansmath
  \IfFileExists{sansmathaccent.sty}
    {\RequirePackage{sansmathaccent}}
    {}
\fi
```

And in `sansmathaccent.sty` we find:

```
% Check to see if we are a Beamer document
\@ifpackageloaded{beamerbasefont}{%
    \def\sansmathaccent@warning{}

    % Ensure proper placement of accents with bm
    % but don't waste a mathgroup unless we will in fact use
    % bm and pureletters
    \IfFileExists{filehook.sty}{
        \RequirePackage{filehook}
        \AtBeginOfFile{bm.sty}{     
            \beamer@font@check \ifbeamer@suppressreplacements\else
            \DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{OT1}{mathkerncmss}{m}{sl}
            \SetSymbolFont{pureletters}{bold}{OT1}{mathkerncmss}{bx}{sl}
            \fi
        }
    }{
        \DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{OT1}{mathkerncmss}{m}{sl}
        \SetSymbolFont{pureletters}{bold}{OT1}{mathkerncmss}{bx}{sl}
        \PackageWarning{sansmathaccent}{Could not find 'filehooks' package: one mathgroup may be wasted}
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, because it works! To be honest I m a bit scared of this :) I googled about \csname and did not understand anything! Can I pls ask you: why it works in article and not beamer? Is there a more basic way (I m scared of using something I dont understand at all)? Thanks again!!

Comment: `\@@input` is the original TeX `\input` which is expandable. The LaTeX `\input` isn't, but I have not checked in detail exactly how it leads to failure here. You can put in preamble `\makeatletter\let\xxinput\@@input\makeatother` and then use `\xxinput`. Note that with TeX's `\input` you don't use braces for the file name, but it is delimited by a space (here end of line space) or a `\relax`.

Comment: `\csname @@input\endcsname` is only because `\@@input` would have required `\makeatletter` but then the file will be read with `@` having the  "letter" catcode which may be not expected (although it should cause no harm; more worrisome is the contrary situation where `@` actually *should* be of catcode "letter" but has kept its "other" catcode setting.) Hence better to do as in my previous comment a once and for all definition of `\xxinput` and use that, probably less scary ;-)

Comment: The issue was not one of expandability per se, but the fact that `beamer` (via `filehook.sty`) adds a post file input hook which causes impossibility to use  `\input` to insert LaTeX code  in the document and expect it to behave (in full generality) as if it was textually already there in the document, in the case where the inserted code is supposed to manipulate the tokens located in document after insertion point.

Comment: @JosephWright the `Could not find 'filehooks' package` appears to be a typo in `sansmathaccent.sty` (last line of my excerpt at bottom of answer), should be `'filehook'`.

Comment: thx again. What you said, ie "which causes impossibility to use \input to insert LaTeX code in the document and expect it to behave (in full generality) as if it was textually already there in the document" is very worrying for me since i need to quite heavily use \input in beamer. How should I behave/what kind of things should i be aware of? In other words, would it be possible for you to kind of produce examples where using \input in beamer will give me troubles?

Comment: you will have troubles each time you externalize some macros to a file and these macros when input are supposed to act on what comes next in your document, producing more tokens out of it. Thus typically `\foreach` but many other things. Just use `\xxinput` with `\xxinput` having been let to `\@@input` in preamble and you will be fine.